# select view model list from joined linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple join in a `linq` statement

```
var events = (from e in context.Events
join o in context.Offices on e.OfficeId equals o.Id
where e.StartDate >= DateTime.Now
select e)
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new vm_Events()
{
    Cost = x.Cost,
    StartDate = x.StartDate,
    EndDate = x.EndDate.HasValue ? (x.EndDate).Value : new DateTime(),
    Address = x.Address,
    Image = x.SupportingImage,
    Info = x.Info,
    Name = x.Name,
    LocationName = x.LocationName,
    Office =
        string.Format("For more information please call the {0} office at {1}", x.Offices.Name,
            x.Offices.PhoneNumber),
    StateZip = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", x.City, x.State, x.Zip)
}).ToList();
```

The query builds just fine but gives me null references when I include the joined `offices` table. Do I need to change `select e` to anything else before the `.AsEnumerable()` call?

*I have verified that the data I'm looking for on the offices table is not null*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `x.Offices.Name` after `AsEnumerable` if you have no lazy-loading. I advice you to make two steps:

1. Load all data you need in anonymous class
2. Build your vm_Events object

---

```
var events = (from e in context.Events
join o in context.Offices on e.OfficeId equals o.Id
where e.StartDate >= DateTime.Now
select e)
.Select(x => new
{
    Cost = x.Cost,
    StartDate = x.StartDate,
    EndDate = x.EndDate.HasValue ? (x.EndDate).Value : new DateTime(),
    Address = x.Address,
    Image = x.SupportingImage,
    Info = x.Info,
    Name = x.Name,
    LocationName = x.LocationName,
    OfficeName = x.Offices.Name,
    OfficePhoneNumber = x.Offices.PhoneNumber,
    x.City,
    x.State, 
    x.Zip
}).ToList()
.Select(x=> new vm_Events
{
    Cost = x.Cost,
    StartDate = x.StartDate,
    EndDate = x.EndDate,
    Address = x.Address,
    Image = x.SupportingImage,
    Info = x.Info,
    Name = x.Name,
    LocationName = x.LocationName,
    Office = string.Format("For more information please call the {0} office at {1}", x.OfficeName, x.OfficePhoneNumber),
    StateZip = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", x.City, x.State, x.Zip)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: @JonHarding you are wellcome